# How to best show an activity state transition adhering to google's material design component framework?

Tags: web-app, android, material-design, status, activity-feed

I have an application which consist of three views for an activity. A list View, A chat view.  Every activity has a status , which a a user can either mark completed, pending

Example of list view: **Check  indicate the status confirmed and pending has no icon**
[image]

Example of chat view : [image]

Currently for changing status, I have a toggle switch control in chat view for marking an activity completed or pending. The feed back is received from users is that the toggle switch is confusing.

Adhering to best UI/UX practices what is the best way to show status change functionality? 
Is it better for a user to change status in list view via button or to change status in conversation

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site, shikhhar!

It may well be that the combination of the term "Activity Completed" and the interactive element causes confuses users. "Activity Completed" is a description of a state. It does not label an action, but rather a state that has already been reached.

To call for an action, it might help to turn the label+switch to a simple button "Complete Activity" or "Set to completed".

I'd also try to use the same design in both the chat and the list.